# Different angle of the same Data set in different map layouts

Tags: arcmap, layouts

I am trying to create a new layout - to get the bigger area of the map.
I used the same data: raster, vector.
Even if north arrow showing on the north in both cases:
there is a difference:

The original:

[image]

new one:

[image]

What can be a problem?

Comment: You're probably not displaying the new one in the same coordinate reference system as the old one, hence the apparent distortion.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the Coordinate system of your new layout's dataframe to same as the original one, from your **Dataframe Properties** > **Coordinate System tab**. They seems like in different Coordinate Systems.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the projecting is different for both your raster. 
Check your data frame properties to see your projection and make sure it is same for both your rasters. You can change the projection by going to Properties > Coordinate System.